# Why is there no conditional inference rule in Sequent Calculus of these forms?

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

I'm wondering why sequent calculus doesn't have rules like these (at least in the ones I've come across):
$$
\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B, \Pi \qquad \Delta \vdash A, \Sigma \over
\Gamma, \Delta \vdash B, \Pi, \Sigma
$$
And
$$
\Gamma, A \rightarrow B \vdash \Pi \qquad \Delta, A \vdash \Sigma \over
\Gamma, \Delta, A \rightarrow B, A \vdash \Pi \land B, \Sigma
$$
Perhaps they are unnecessary because we can derive the same thing using? But I don't see how as we don't have any rules that involve a conditional on the left or right, above the inference line.

I feel like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding sequent calculus, as I still think in terms of natural deduction.

Comment: At least in Boolos' _Computability and Logic_, these rules are not included because implication itself (i.e. $p\to q$) is not included either, but is rather a simplification of $\neg p\lor q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a sentence $P$ holds in first-order classical logic, then you can derive $\vdash P$ using the rules present in the usual Gentzen sequent calculus LK. No other rules are necessary. You don't need to add *any* extra rules, in particular you don't need to add rules like the one you suggest. That should answer your question.

*Why* does this hold? Well, the proper explanation depends on which sources you're using, and how these define first-order classical logic in the first place. Some works and authors define first-order classical logic as precisely the things you can prove using the rules of the sequent calculus LK, in which case the statement is trivial. Other authors define first-order classical logic using derivability in another formal proof system, such as a Hilbert system or a system of Natural Deduction: in that case, there will be a proof showing that the derivable sentences in LK and the system used to define first-order logic coincide. Yet other works define first-order logic using some kind of semantics (e.g. a Tarskian model-theoretic semantics): in this case, you'd have a theorem showing that LK is *sound and complete* for the semantics.

This should answer your titular question: we don't have these rules because we don't need them.

In systems where $\rightarrow$ is a basic connective, not defined in terms of others like $\wedge$ amd $\neg$, the usual rules governing it have the form

$$\frac{\Gamma, A \vdash B, \Delta}{\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B, \Delta} $$

and

$$\frac{\Gamma, B \vdash \Delta \:\:\: \Gamma \vdash A, \Delta}{\Gamma, A \rightarrow B \vdash \Delta} $$

instead of the ones you suggest. In calculi where $\rightarrow$ is a defined connective, you don't need separate rules for it, you can just replace it with its definition.

Do you have trouble deriving some specific formula involving $\rightarrow$ in the sequent calculus? If so, you can put it into [Logitext](http://logitext.mit.edu/main) and click around to see where you get stuck. If that doesn't help, you can always ask a more specific question here (but make sure you explain clearly which particular presentation of sequent calculus you're using, and reference the textbook where you found it!).

> I feel like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding sequent calculus, as I still think in terms of natural deduction.

Alas, based on the question, I suspect so too. I'll give you a few pointers here.

We study the sequent calculus because it makes it easy to analyze proofs. This is accomplished by theorems such as *cut-elimination* and the *subformula property*, which ensure that when you're searching for a proof, you don't have to make certain types of "clever guesses".

Let's take a simple example.

You might want to prove logic consistent, by showing that $\vdash X$ for an atomic formula $X$ has no derivation.

When you search for a proof in sequent calculus, you go bottom-up. Starting with the desired conclusion, you try to apply the rules to reach axioms $\Gamma, Y \vdash Y, \Delta$ where some formula $Y$ occurs on both the left and the right of the turnstile.

You can easily show that $\vdash X$ has no derivation which doesn't use the cut rule: such a proof would eventually have to conclude with one or more axiom rules $\Gamma, Y \vdash Y, \Delta$. But the only rules you can apply to an atomic $X$ are weakening and contraction, which always yield sequents of the form $\vdash X, X, \dots, X$, and never let you get a formula on the left of the turnstile at all. But to apply the axiom rule, some formula $Y$ would have to occur on both the left and the right of the turnstile. Since this never happens, $\vdash X$ has no proof that doesn't use the cut rule.

It's much harder to show that $\vdash X$ has no derivation using the cut rule. Recall that the cut rule has the form

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A, \Sigma \:\:\: \Delta, A \vdash \Pi}{\Gamma, \Delta \vdash \Sigma, \Pi}\text{cut}$$

Having the cut rule comes in handy when we want to combine proofs together, but turns into a major annoyance when we try to prove that something has *no* derivation. Maybe we can choose a really clever non-atomic formula $A$ and prove both $\vdash A$ and $A \vdash X$! It's only thanks to Gentzen's Hauptsatz (the cut-elimination theorem), a very difficult result, that we know this cannot happen.

Now notice that your first proposed rule would give rise to the same problem as the cut rule: maybe we could guess some very clever $A$, and prove $\vdash A \rightarrow X$ and $\vdash A$. We don't want such non-analytic rules in our sequent system, and if we had it, our utmost priority would be to show that it's never necessary to use this rule.

Comment: Ah, I didn’t realized that when people write multi sets in the inference rules, they could be empty.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Logitext, itwas super helpful to see how the structure of sequent calculus is optimal for proof search

Comment: I asked the question because I was doing some research into substructural logic (motivated as a solution to paradoxes like Curry’s), and needed sequent calculus to make clear of what structural rules a proof is employing. But because most of the example proofs I came across are proofs of a singular falsum with no premise, or the empty sequent, it was hard to make out how to prove more ordinary things in Sequent Calculus.